# How to get the directory from an URL using JS?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have one URL which is

```
https://hpscrmdev.honeywell.com/service_enu_dv2_oui/start.swe?SWECmd=GotoView&SWEView=Home+Page+View+(WCC)&SWERF=1&SWEHo=hpscrmdev.honeywell.com&SWEBU=1
```

I want this 'service_enu_dv2_oui' part using regex. How can I get that?
Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it *have* to be regex? What environment is this in? Because if you're working with a Location object, it's already broken up into pieces for you.

Comment: `window.location.pathname.split('\/')[1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is without regex but working nicely: http://jsfiddle.net/mKNkF/

```
var path = "https://hpscrmdev.honeywell.com/service_enu_dv2_oui/start.swe?SWECmd=GotoView&SWEView=Home+Page+View+(WCC)&SWERF=1&SWEHo=hpscrmdev.honeywell.com&SWEBU=1";

var pathArray = path.split( '/' );

alert(pathArray[3]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the path only has a single segment as shown in your example, the regex is fairly straight-forward:

```
/^http(?:s?):\/\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)/
```

[Live link](http://regex101.com/#javascript) with details.

For example:

```
var str = "https://hpscrmdev.honeywell.com/service_enu_dv2_oui/start.swe?SWECmd=GotoView&SWEView=Home+Page+View+(WCC)&SWERF=1&SWEHo=hpscrmdev.honeywell.com&SWEBU=1";
var match = str.match(/^http(?:s?):\/\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)/);
if (match) {
    console.log(match[1]); // "service_enu_dv2_oui"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Path without host and query you can receive from

```
window.location.pathname
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

No regex required

Answer (score 0):

`https?:\/\/[\w\.]+\/(\w+)\/`
this regex have one match group

you check [this link](http://regex101.com/r/gO8pR0)